# Assign Radio Group to Radio Buttons

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode-storyboard

I have several radio buttons

[image]

I need to assign a radio group to it so that only one radio button is selectable at a time.There is no radio group option.I have tried

- Assigning a single action outlet to all buttons
- Putting all buttons in a custom view

None of this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old days, `NSMatrix` was the class that provided the radio group behavior. If you look up the docs for that class, you'll find the following note:

> Use of NSMatrix is discouraged in apps that run in macOS 10.8 and later. If you need to create a radio button group in an app that runs in macOS 10.8 and later, create instances of NSButton that each specify a button type of NSRadioButton and specify the same action and the same superview for each button in the group.

So there are *three* things that all need to be true at the same time for this to work:

- Your buttons all have to share the same superview.
- Your buttons all have to have the same action.
- Your buttons need to have their *button type* set to NSRadioButton.

I tried this out just now. I created a button in a view in my storyboard, set it's button type to "Radio" in the Attributes inspector, and assigned an action. Then I duplicated that button several times, and ran the app. The radio behavior worked automatically.

If it's not working for you, I'd start by doing what I did above. Just create a single radio button and set it up with an action. Then duplicate it a few times and test. If that works (it should), then either see if you can use that technique to get what you want, or look at what's different between what you want and what works.

Comment: Your approach worked.. I don't understand why apple has omitted such a critical requirement.A radio group property would have worked fine.

Comment: Glad it works! It's a very easy behavior to write yourself if you don't like theirs. The old way, which involved NSMatrix and NSCell, was just more complicated than it needed to be. The down side to the current approach is that the way to get it to work isn't obvious.

Comment: NSRadioButton is deprecated after macOS 10.14

Comment: @RickJansen: you had me a bit confused there. Radio buttons themselves are not deprecated; merely the `NSButtonType` constant name `NSRadioButton` is deprecated in favor of the Swift-style replacement constant name `NSButtonTypeRadio`.

Comment: These days you just connect NSButtons in one view, like an NSBox, to the same action, and they’ll be treated like radio buttons.

Comment: @Caleb -- one piece that is missing and no one writes about: how can you QUERY the "group" to find out which button is the presently active button?

Comment: @SMGreenfield If you need to query the group, you’re using views to store data, which is a Bad Thing. Selecting a radio button should cause an update to your data model, so your model should already know which button is selected. Even in SwiftUI, controls are bound to local state instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Caleb -- you raise a good point.  OTOH, all other controls have a method to query their state.  In my case, I'm converting an older app to separate model from view, but there were a few places where it made sense to query the radio group from the controller code.

Comment: @SMGreenfield A radio group isn't a control, it's several individual controls. Even old-style NSMatrix-based radio groups really just used the matrix as a container, IIRC. You can query each of the buttons until you find the one that's on, or it'd be simple to write a NSControl subclass that manages a group of radio buttons...

Comment: @Caleb - writing a method that queries each one is what I've done in the past, and done now.  I was just hoping there was a built in solution -- but you clearly pointed out WHY there wouldn't be, and of course it gets to the heart of proper MVC design.  Thanks!

Comment: "Radio" doesn't seem to be an attribute option as of the most recent Xcode Storyboard version in 2023, despite comments in 2022? Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelPlischke You seem to be. In Xcode 14.2, I can still create buttons and set both the *style* and *type* to "Radio". Note that this question is tagged [tag:macos]; iOS doesn't support radio buttons (although it does have segmented buttons, which can provide similar functionality).

Comment: Ah, that must be it. Thanks for clarifying - I'm building for IOS lol