# Missing Identifier for Radio Button when trying to identify the Sender

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to identify the clicked radio button using the Interface builder identifier.

[image]

```
 @IBAction func text_radio_changed(_ sender: Any) {
        let button:NSButton = sender as! NSButton
        let id:String = button.accessibilityIdentifier()
        print("===========>"+id)
    }
```

But the console keeps printing this

```
===========>
```

There is no identifier

Comment: You can connect an IBOutlet to each button, change your method signature to (_ button: NSButton)` and then `switch button { case button1: ... case button2 ... default: break }`

Comment: @LeoDabus what is 'button1' ? Identifier ?

Comment: you can choose any name you want when you connect an IBOutlet to your button

Comment: @LeoDabus All radio buttons are connected to a single outlet.Only 1 is manually connected, rest is copy pasted.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If you created your button programmatically is the name of your var. If you created it using storyboard you can choose any name when connecting it to an IBOutlet

Comment: @LeoDabus Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/61243810/848968

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button.accessibilityIdentifier` is the Accessibility Identity Identifier. The Identity Identifier is `button.identifier`.

```
@IBAction func text_radio_changed(_ sender: Any) {
    let button:NSButton = sender as! NSButton
    let id:String = button.identifier!.rawValue
    print("===========>"+id)
}
```

Comment: I had tried this but button.identifier is not a string.Have you debugged your code ?

Answer (score 1):

On your code you are actually trying to access the accessibility identifier which is a different thing. To identify the radio button you should use tags. Set a tag for the button and then read it like this.

```
@IBAction func text_radio_changed(_ sender: Any) {
    let button:NSButton = sender as! NSButton
    let id:Int = button.tag
    print("===========>"+id)
}
```

*Note: You can actually do use the accessibility id to do the same thing. Check this other similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055575/10241612).*

***Update***: The answer by "Willeke" seems better (if it works), I am used to developing for iOS and I wasn't aware there is an identifier property for NSButtons.

Comment: I knew that tag can be used to achieve the same.But I prefer a string rather than a number

Comment: You can use an enum to hold all the different values and give them string equivalents. Alternatively take a look the hyperlink in my answer with instruction on how to use the accessibility identifier that uses strings.